# Facebook error: An access token is required to request this resource

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

I use a plugin called Socialist to fetch facebook images.

When runnning on my site I get this error (firebug console):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/in1dotcom/photos?limit=7 400 Bad Request 222ms

{
"error": {
"message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 104
}
}
```

HEADERS WHEN RUNING WITHIN IN MY WEBSITE USING SOCIALIST PLUGIN:

```
Request URL:********
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:cookie-agreed-en=2; Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight=0; Drupal.toolbar.collapsed=0; SESS698a29b8d8c900ba7e7794565975ca75=1b_V4T71CnFDWA24ug9dMc2ZWk4YOdQ8eyy1FQvwMZI; has_js=1
Host::********
If-Modified-Since:Sun, 28 Apr 2013 18:43:15 +0000
If-None-Match:"1367174595"
Referer::********
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Language:en
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 28 Apr 2013 18:45:40 GMT
ETag:"1367174740"
Expires:Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Sun, 28 Apr 2013 18:45:40 +0000
Link:<http://:********>; rel="shortlink",<:********>; rel="canonical"
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Generator:Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.4
```

HEADERS WHEN RUNING DURECT IN MY BROWSER:

```
Request URL:http://graph.facebook.com/in1dotcom/photos?limit=7
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:datr=mhdvUW42_Gu_woq3PP7hPhaj
Host:graph.facebook.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
limit:7
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1058
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 28 Apr 2013 18:47:44 GMT
ETag:"87876279654a470b76b73924ea9b095fb9cc4b75"
Expires:Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
X-FB-Debug:dWTXe1fRmxaCxH3bhi7yHfTuVUlE1Th0s2Fwn50u+r4=
X-FB-Rev:798183
```

But if I run `http://graph.facebook.com/in1dotcom/photos?limit=7` directly in the browser it works fine.

I even tried different facebook pages (including the authors demo above) incase it was a permissions issue but I experinced the same results.

Here is a link to the plugin:

[jquery.socialist.js](https://raw.github.com/iatek/jquery-socialist/master/jquery.socialist.js)

You can see a working demo here:

http://plugins.in1.com/socialist/demo#social

Any ideas on why this is happening.

Regards
C

NOTE:
I've tried logged in and out of facebook, same results. This plugin says it doesn't require you to be logged in or authenticated. It only grabs photos and without auth the only thing that FB makes available are "photos" -- not "posts", "news", "status", etc.

Please also note that it seems to be working perfectly on the demo site (above) using the same facebook id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple possibilities you could check:

1. You're getting rate limited. In this case, it seems that some number of anonymous requests are allowed per unit time, but past that you must be authenticated. If that's the case, simply waiting will fix the problem, although you'd need to make sure you understand how rate limiting works so your app doesn't fall over under use.
2. You're getting filtered according to `User-Agent`. Can you post the request headers for each request (browser-based, and for socialist)?

**EDIT**: From the comments below, via the original asker @Cybercampbell:

> ok... I download the .js from the working demo website and compared it to the .js in the downloaded package and found this difference in the ajax call: beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Firefox/6.0');}, and this: dataType:'json' became this: dataType:'jsonp' I added this and now it works... I guess they are just a little befind in updating their files

Looks like the issue is in an out-of-date Socialist distribution. Caveat emptor! And great detective work @Cybercampbell!

Comment: Hi @sigpwned - point 1 seems unlikley. The site is in development so it's only me and so not excessive.  Plus it works fine when running directly in any browser. I don't know how to get headers. What's the best way to get that info?

Comment: Please headers post above.

Comment: Let's start with the browser headers since they're easy to find. If you're in Chrome, for example, you can use Chrome's developer tools under `View --> Developer --> Developer tools` (on my Mac, at least). From there, you can find the individual request under the `Network` tab, and then under the request you can find the headers under the `Headers` tab. From there, we'll connect directly to the Facebook servers using something like `nc` and try (a) the exact request from your browser; and then (b) the exact request from your browser *with `User-Agent` changed* to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Perfect! I see the headers. Are these headers from your browser, or from your App? (Presumably, they're from the App, since it appears to be a failure.)

Comment: They are from the plugin which runs in my browser.

Comment: Can you post headers from your "by hand" test too? It'll be instructive to do a comparison between the headers to see what's different.

Comment: reposted following your instruction for chrome.

Comment: I'm not logged into facebook and I have the same results both logged in and not. I also have the same results in Chrome where I never log into facebook.

Comment: You're right. I seem to have jumped the gun with the above. I'm testing another theory now.

Comment: Thanks @sigpwned. In any case this plugin says it doesn't require you to be logged in or authenticated. It only grabs photos and without auth the only thing that FB makes available are "photos" -- not "posts", "news", "status", etc..

Comment: I've taken the headers from your Socialist plugin and tried them verbatim against Facebook using `nc`, and they work. Odd. I did notice one thing, though: the URL, Host, and Referer headers in the Social headers dump are all blanked out (filled with `****`). Do you have those values? I filled in "sane" values when I tried and got success; is it possible you're requesting against a "bad" URL?

Comment: Thanks @sigpwned. My NDA wont allow me to post the domain info but I tried it local (MAMP) and on my server wih the same results. This is so strange. It all worked fine last week.

Comment: No worries, I understand NDAs. Very odd. If you're trying the same request from the same server using two different programs and getting two different results, then I'd say it's time to pull out the packet sniffer. There's got to be some difference between the requests, and you'll need something like tcpdump to see it.

Comment: Here is a download link to the demo from the official website... same issue yet there online demo works.

http://www.filedropper.com/iatek-jquery-socialist-c00af4f

Comment: ok... I download the .js from the working demo website and compared it to the .js in the downloaded package and found this difference in the ajax call:

`beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Firefox/6.0');},`

and this:
`dataType:'json'` became this: `dataType:'jsonp'`


I added this and now it works... I guess they are just a little befind in updating their files

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to help @sigpwned. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: Updated. Happy to spend the time! Hope it helped!